# Westworld S01E02: How did they get to the park by an elevator inside a moving train?

Tags: westworld-tv

There are pretty suitable explanations why the [guests can't be harmed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63275/what-protects-the-westworld-guests-from-injuries-caused-by-weapons-other-than-gu) or [how do the hosts work](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63274/what-exactly-is-the-physiology-of-hosts-in-the-westworld-tv-series). Though, there is still something I can not figure out.

When the new two guests come into the Westworld in the second episode of the first series, they get to the park by an elevator that leads inside a **moving** train. How is this possible?

Is the *Westworld* park a real thing within the TV show? How else could they have gotten inside the moving train?

Comment: *"Is the Westworld real?"* No. It's just a TV show.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Obviously I didn't mean the Westworld series but the Westworld park the Westworld series is about because it didn't make sense to me several times but the moving train seems like the last thing that doesn't make sense to me so I edited the question.

Comment: You should probably remove the last question from the text because it differs from the question in the title. Still I don't think this question should be downvoted. +1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is the Delos Westworld park a physical place in the TV show?

## Absolutely

There is no doubt that the park is a physical place (although we don't know *where* it is).

You have to travel to the receiving area in a train (the white high-tech, bullet train version).

[image]

The hosts are physical constructs...we see them being made and interacted with in the inner workings of the park **and** they are put into storage when not being used.

---

> they get to the park by an elevator that leads inside a moving train.

As for the elevator...there is no evidence that the train is **moving** when they board it. The scene suggests that the carriage is **standing still** until a certain point when it starts moving...as indicated by the overhead light starting to vibrate.

Then it seems that the 'Western' train simply comes out of a tunnel.

Comment: "we don't know where it is" Well, it's obviously in the US southwest, likely Utah (where they shot it). ([Vasquez Rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasquez_Rocks) not withstanding.)

Comment: @user1118321, except in a later episode, Ford says to another character, "...when you get back to the mainland", which indicates the park(s) are on an island.

Comment: Or that the park is a world on it's own, *like* an island.

Comment: @StijndeWitt The park is definitely on Earth. There are shots of Earth's moon at several points in the show, and a reference to the constellation Orion. Most likely it is a large artificial island.

Comment: 'A world on it's own' wasn't meant literally. If you can only go into the park via one central passage way (the train ride) it may start to *feel* like an island or a peninsula.

Comment: @stinjin I feel fairly sure that S. World is across the water way/lake, because of one scene that is shown in the season two teaser promo. In addition we know that SW "creative" is also inside the Delos facility as seen in final scenes of season 1. But it's unclear if the entry way and guest quarters to SW is then different, despite sharing buildings?

Comment: Also I would like to point out that Cold Storage looks like it may have once been another transportation hub, perhaps from it's founding days...I'm curious if it's completely sealed off or if it allows for another entry way into the park?